# View with editable textviews (onClick)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a view with several textView. I want them to be editable on Click. 
Following code seems not to do what is supposed to do:

```
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    textView1.setText(tv1);
    runEditListener(textView1);


    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    textView2.setText(tv2);
    runEditListener(textView1);
```

.......

```
    private void runEditListener(TextView textView) {

    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    editText = new EditText(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Edit");
    dialog.setView(editText);
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { textView.setText(editText.getText());

        }
    });

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            editText.setText(textView.getText());
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

I probably should only run once the runEditListener() method and get on which TextView the user clicked but I don't really find how to do that.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about what you want to do ? and what is not working?

Comment: yes, I have a view, full of textView, which are all properties from a repo. User needs to see those properties and be able to edit them if needed. 

So i made one textView per property and added the click functionality to edit it according to this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ManYWNqKJo

Now this works great for one textview but not for multiple. So I figured out that I need to extract the click functionality on a more abstract layer and just get on which textView I clicked and then edit this one. Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better implement a unified `onClickListener()`

**Activity**

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
        textView1.setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);
        textView2.setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView textView3 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_3);
        textView3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        final TextView textView = (TextView) v;

        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setText(textView.getText());

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        dialog.setTitle("Edit");
        dialog.setView(editText);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                textView.setText(editText.getText());
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**ButterKnife**
With **ButterKnife** it is simpler, and you dont need to exclusively implement `View.OnClickListener`

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        // ButterKnife Binder
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    // ButterKnife OnClick
    @OnClick({R.id.text_view_1, R.id.text_view_2, R.id.text_view_3})
    void onClickTextView(final TextView textView)
    {
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setText(textView.getText());

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        dialog.setTitle("Edit");
        dialog.setView(editText);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                textView.setText(editText.getText());
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Butterknife worked out perfectly! Thanks! Just an additional question now, Suppose The value of textView is read from some variable/repo. What is a good practice on how the write data back to the variable? Please see this example: https://pastebin.com/aJiDBwgM

Answer (score 0):

You call the dialog in a public void. Shouldn't the dialog be final then?
The same for textView, that is also called inside a public void.

Answer (score 0):

Create OnClickListener with your code from runEdit... then set it to yours textviews like `textview.onClickLiatener(yourListener);`
you can do it by implementing OnClickListener for your activity class and then use `text1.onClickListener(this);
text2.onClickListener(this);` etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setFocusable(true);
textView.setEnabled(true);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit?  Just commenting out my own runEditListener() and adding those properties to my textView won't make it editable.